# Как отключить некоторые стандартные функции окна консоли?

Tags: c#, winapi, консоль

Пишу консольную игру, в связи с этим понадобилось отключить следующие функции:

1. Изменение размера окна консоли перетаскиванием рамок, а также
   нажатием кнопки 'Развернуть на весь экран'.
2. Стандартную функцию выделения текста комбинациями вида
   Shift+Стрелка. Следующий вариант не работает:

   ```
   hConsoleWindow = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
   GetConsoleMode(hConsoleWindow, out uint сonsoleMode);
   consoleMode &= ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT;
   SetConsoleMode(hConsoleWindow, consoleMode);
   ```

   Примечание: `GetConsoleWindow()` вместо `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle` также не дает результата.
3. Обработку мыши (в том числе выделение текста в месте клика мышью или
   с помощью движения мыши с зажатой левой клавишей).

В идеале, хотелось бы также полностью отключить системное меню окна консоли (то что появляется после правого клика в области заголовка окна).

***Обновление:*** 
 
1-я задача, а также отключение меню окна консоли, решена благодаря **Максиму** и **nick_n_a**. 
 
2-я задача также решена - оказалось что в Windows 10 почему-то ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE имеет прямо противоположный смысл, так что нужно использовать именно ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT.
 
Осталось решить только 3-ю задачу, с отключением возможности выделения текста в окне консоли с помощью мыши.

Comment: Через WINAPI ф-ция SetWindowLong. (GWL_STYLE)

Comment: Для мыши... нужно либо читать мышь самому readconsoleinput https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput в цикле в отдельном потоке. Либо... больше склоняюсь к версии - перехватить мышь http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-mouse-hook-in-c/ (тогда консоль не получит сообщений мыши вообще)

Comment: 3.1 сделать SetConsoleMode + ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT. и отдельным потоком readconsoleinput. Не люблю хуки. Но можно и хуком.

Comment: nick_n_a, я тоже не люблю хуки :). ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT пробовал, но это никак не повлияло на возможность выделения текста в окне консоли с помощью мыши. Ладно, если без перехвата и самостоятельной обработки "мышинных" сообщений никак, значит придётся смирится и оставить всё как есть (всё равно это не критично и, в отличии от, например, изменения рамера окна, не сломает вывод "игровой графики").

Answer (score 1):

У консольного приложения нет окна как такового, только содержание.
Приложения-обертки консольных приложений создают это окно.
В Windows у cmd.exe есть некоторые настройки этого окна.

Часть из них доступна в C#, например:

```
Console.CursorVisible = false;
```

И другие...

Полагаться на них сильно не стоит.

Что бы получить доступ к окну, понадобятся некоторые WinAPI функции.
Нужно найти окно, и изменить необходимые флаги:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Projects
{
    public class Test
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport ( "user32.dll" )]
        static extern int SetWindowLong ( IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong );

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern UInt32 GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        public static int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        public static uint WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");

            IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("ConsoleWindowClass", null); //Здесь ищем первое попавшееся консольное окно
            if(hwnd != null) {
                SetWindowLong(
                    hwnd,
                    GWL_STYLE,
                    GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) ^ WS_THICKFRAME
                );
                Console.WriteLine("Рамки сделаны не изменяемыми!");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но зачем сложности с FindWindow, если GetConsoleWindow тоже возвращает хэндл окна консоли для текущего консольного приложения?

Comment: Это для примера. Можно и так.